# On / Off function after a certain period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering how you can make .off() only happen for a specific period of time. I have a div which once clicked i want to disable the click event for 2 seconds, and then be allowed to click again. At the moment all I have is the div can be clicked, then once clicked it is off.

Here is a brief example of what I am asking:

```
$('.test').on('click', function() {
    // *do stuff*
    $('.test').off('click'); *for a certain perdiod of time*
});
```

Comment: Use window.setTimeout(function() { // code execute atfer 1 second }, 1000)

Answer (score 2):

It's a much simpler task to use a boolean variable as a flag to state whether the click handler should be executed, instead of attaching/detaching events from multiple elements. Try this:

```
var clickEnabled = true;

$('div').click(function() {
    clickEnabled = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        clickEnabled = true;
    }, 2000);
});

$('.test').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!clickEnabled) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // do stuff...
    }
});
```

Note that you should also make the fact that `.test` is disabled visible in the UI, otherwise you'll just confuse and annoy your visitors when they click an element expecting an action, but nothing happens.

Comment: @PraveenKumar absolutely, OP only stated he was using a `div` element as the trigger for disabling the event though, so I used that as an example.

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks. the div is a nav menu, so basically what I want it to do is be clicked, then fully transition, and then be able to be closed.

Comment: If you're using the `animate()` method for the transitions you could use callback functions instead of the timer which would be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

What about activate on after a certain period of time?

```
function myFunction() {
   ...do stuff
   $('.test').off('click'); for a certain perdiod of time
   setTimeout(function(){ $('.test').on('click', myFunction)}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the setTimeout you may do something like:

```js
var enabled = true;
var timeoutSeconds = 2;

$(function () {
  $('.test').on('click', function(e) {
    if (enabled) {
      // *do stuff*
      enabled = false;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        enabled = true;
      }, timeoutSeconds * 1000);
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
function onClick() {

  // do stuff here

  $('.test').off('click');

  setTimeout(function(){
       $('.test').on('click', onClick);
  }, 2000)
}

$('.test').on('click', onClick);
```

Or you can do it with css and toggleClass

```
// css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}

// js
$('.test').on('click', function(){
   // do stuff here

   $('.test').addClass('disabled');
   setTimeout(function(){
     $('.test').removeClass('disabled');
   }, 2000);
});
```